# Как проверить "путь" к элементу json на корректность?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть большая и запутанная json-схема. Нужно вытащить из неё несколько значений.

```
var result = res.query.pages[45454].revisions[0].slots.main["*"];
```

Можно ли как-то быстро проверить, существует ли элемент по такому пути и правилен ли сам путь (все ли элементы в наличии)? Банально, не выдаёт ли "путь" ошибок null или undefined. Чтобы не выстраивать вот такие лесенки в ад:

```
        if (res.hasOwnProperty("query"))
            if (res.query.hasOwnProperty("pages"))
                if (res.query.pages.hasOwnProperty(45454))
                    if (res.query.pages[45454].hasOwnProperty("revisions"))
                        if (res.query.pages[45454].revisions.hasOwnProperty(0))
                            if (res.query.pages[45454].revisions[0].hasOwnProperty("slots"))
                                if (res.query.pages[45454].revisions[0].slots.hasOwnProperty("main"))
                                    if (res.query.pages[45454].revisions[0].slots.main.hasOwnProperty("*"))
                                        var result = res.query.pages[45454].revisions[0].slots.main["*"];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Проверить наличие *объектного* свойства можно таким образом (используя то что объект в JS всегда является truthy значением):

```
const isPropExists = Boolean(res?.query?.pages?.[45454]?.revisions?.[0]?.slots?.main);
```

Получение значения глубоко вложенного свойства `main`, соотв. может выглядеть как:

```
// конечно же, тут результатом может оказаться и null, и undefined, но ошибок брошено не будет
let main = res?.query?.pages?.[45454]?.revisions?.[0]?.slots?.main;

// а тут мы используем fallback-значение (новый пустой объект) 
main = res?.query?.pages?.[45454]?.revisions?.[0]?.slots?.main ?? {};
```

Наличие свойств *примитивных* типов, можно проверять множеством способов. Самое очевидное - именно тип значения и проверять. Для облегчения восприятия кода при таких проверках, можно использовать простые функции-хелперы:

```
// где-то в src/utils/some-helpful-stuff.js объявим (с последующим экспортом)...
const checkType = (type, val) => typeof val === type,
      isBool = checkType.bind(this, 'boolean'),
      isString = checkType.bind(this, 'string');

// ...и в основном коде (с импортами) становится более-менее понятно происходящее
const doWeHaveBoolX = isBool(res?.query?.pages?.[45454]?.revisions?.[0]?.slots?.main?.x),
      resHasStringY = isString(res?.query?.pages?.[45454]?.revisions?.[0]?.slots?.main?.y);
```

---

**MDN:**

- [Оператор опциональной последовательности `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (ES11+)
- [Оператор нулевого слияния `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (ES11+)

Answer (score 4):

Оператор опциональной последовательности `?.` проверяет наличие как собственных свойств, так и прототипных. Если же нужно проверить наличие свойства по цепочке именно ***собственных*** свойств вложенных объектов, то можно использовать подобную функцию с рекурсивным вызовом:

```js
function getNestedProp(obj, path, type) {
  if (!Array.isArray(path)) {
    path = path
      .replace(/([^\\])(\[['"`]?|\.|['"`]?\]\.)/g, '$1\0')
      .replace(/\\\./g, '.')
      .split('\0');
  }
  var len = path.length,
      prop = len && path.shift();
  if (!prop) {
    var isFail = len || ((typeof type === 'string') && (typeof obj !== type));
    return isFail ? void(0) : obj;
  }  
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return getNestedProp(obj[prop], path, type);
}


const res = { a: { b: { c: [{ 'd.e': { f: { g: 'win' }}}]}}};

const getFromRes = getNestedProp.bind(this, res);
console.log(getFromRes('a["b"].c[0].d\\.e.f.g'));  // 'win' (значение последнего свойства в цепочке)
console.log(getFromRes('a.b.c[0].d\\.e.ZZZ.g'));   // undefined (OK: нет свойства `ZZZ`)
console.log(getFromRes('a.b.c[99].d\\.e.f.g'));    // undefined (OK: нет эл-та массива с индексом `99`)
console.log(getFromRes('a.b.c.pop'));              // undefined (OK: `pop` это прототипное св-во массива)

const but = { own: { valueOf: 'seems legit' }};
console.log(getNestedProp(but, 'own.valueOf'));    // 'seems legit' (OK: тут свойство `valueOf` перекрывает прототипное)
// проверка типа встроена
console.log(getNestedProp(but, 'own.valueOf', 'number'));  // undefined (OK: свойство есть, но тип значения не тот)
console.log(getNestedProp(but, 'own.valueOf', 'string'));  // 'seems legit' (и свойство есть, и тип его значения соответствует)
```

Как минимум одним недостатком данной реализации является необходимость экранировать точки в именах свойств (см. в примере `d.e`: экранированно будет `d\.e`, но слэш в js-строке сам по себе требует экранирования, и получаем вид `'d\\.e'`).

*// В функции намеренно использованы только возможности ES5.*

Comment: Если минус из-за проблемы с содержанием ответа, то пожалуйста, хоть парой слов поясните в чем его бесполезность. А если за само добавление второго ответа, то предлагаю первый тоже минуснуть - как для справедливой симметрии (их взаиморанжирование этим не нарушится), так и для усиления осуждающего эффекта.